# Show product view page as two pages in magento

Tags: php

I have a configurable product in magento and I have a requirement to show configurable product options in one page and the custom options, add to cart button in another page. Is is possible to do this? If possible how to pass configurable product option to next page.

Comment: Everything is possible, depending on the amount of effort you want to put in. I won't lie, this is gonna be tricky, you're better off trying to convince your client this is a bad design choice.